# Does running a code multiple time use a lot of memory?

Tags: system

I have just gotten into programming and i realized for every variable that you identify, you use ur computer memory as it is saved in it somewhere.
I wanted to know if I run a piece of code multiple times, would I lose more memory or somehow once you close terminal or program, system deletes it automatically.
THANK YOU

I've run a code several times and every time the address that a same variable is saved in is different.
I believe I'm wasting my computers memory so if I am how do I delete said variables from memory?

Comment: It depends on your OS.  Windows and Linux will clean up once the program exits.  But others might not so you need to free the memory yourself.  Also if you are writing something that never ends (like a service) you will need to free the memory yourself.  If you allocate something on the stack it will go away when the function ends.  If you allocate memory you need to deallocate it.

Comment: If you are using Windows or Linux then the reason why the addresses are different each time is address space layout randomization (ASLR) which keeps other programs from knowing where to look to find data while you program is running.

Comment: It will greatly depends on the language you're using, anyway you'll get more computer knowledge at some point later, there's nothing to worry about for now,you're not losing anything after your program ends, you can focus on coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for all intents and purposes, it is gone the second the program has finished executing.

There are times that this isn't true, but they almost certainly don't apply to you. When on a normal computer or OS running device, the OS (operating system) will clean-up any resources used by your code when it is finished running. This includes all the memory used by declared variables (which is tiny amounts anyway, normally), files you have opened and forgotten to close, and pretty much everything else. OSs are very resilient!

> I've run a code several times and every time the address that a same variable is saved in is different. I believe I'm wasting my computers memory so if I am how do I delete said variables from memory?

These are some pretty good investigative skills (a good sign for someone new to programming), but there are different reasons for this, don't worry. Memory addresses are a complex topic that is worth a look at later down the line, but the simplified story is that memory addresses are different every time you run the program for both security and performance reasons.